# Parameterized SAP PI Mapping

Tags: mapping, integration, sap-pi, sap-xi

Is it possible in SAP PI parameterized mapping to get the value from a field in graphical message mapping and send that value in Java Mapping?

I have a scenario where I am getting the email list from S/4HANA system in graphical mapping but I want to use that email value in the Java Mapping which is another mapping in this scenario. I tried parameter binding but neither the import or export type of parameter is useful in this scenario since none of them can store value.

Kindly let me know if it is possible to achieve or is there any other way to get it in SAP PI system.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if parameters would be your best bet here. They are mainly intended to insert some values on configuration time into mapping at runtime.

You may want to have a look at "using global variables" like here https://blogs.sap.com/2014/10/17/how-to-use-global-variable-in-sap-pi-mapping/

One solution portrayed there is to use the "Edit Java Sections" function within graphical message mapping.

Please beware that I haven't actually tried this, so YMMV